# Cosmetic plug for 3/4" hole in drywall?

Tags: drywall, ethernet

I want to move my router from my office to the hall, directly through the drywall on both sides, and then run the router power cable (low-voltage because it is post-transformer) and two Cat6 cables (one to cable modem and one to switch) straight through the pair of holes. I'd like some sort of plug or bushing (PVC?) to be put into the holes in the drywall so it doesn't just look like a hole in the drywall. It would need to be 3/4" outside diameter. Any ideas?

Happy holidays,
Lud Nom

Comment: Running power cords (even low voltage ones) through walls, is usually frowned upon in most places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install a **low voltage cable port** on each side, such as this.

[image]

Ideally (in my opinion) into a box connected to a box via conduit, but given its low voltage, that's not technically required, as I understand it - **low voltage wall plate mounting brackets** are commonly used rather than boxes

Comment: Thanks. I was really just looking for a plug to place in the hole, sort of like a hollow mushroom. It's OK, though; for example, Comcast ran Coax through walls and just left the holes bare, so I'll just do that.

Answer (score 2):

A partial solution is to install [cat5 jacks](http://www.homedepot.com/b/Electrical-Wall-Plates-Jacks-Wall-Plates-Phone-Data-Wall-Plates/N-5yc1vZc6qy) connected to each other instead of a straight through cable.

[image]

As for the power cable, that is a strange one.  Wouldn't it be better to have the wall wart and cable inside the room?  Trying to do a jack or cable running through a tight conduit is a recipe for built-in obsolescence and/or compatibility.

Comment: Thanks. I planned to plug the router's wall wart into AC power in my home office, and then run the low-voltage cable through the hole in the drywall.