# Ethernet cable from wifi extender into office room through wall

Tags: ethernet

I have a wifi extender on first floor of the house. It is connected into power socket on a wall shared with my home office. The wifi extender is outside the home office since when used inside, its not able to work well. I need to connect to the Ethernet port on this wifi extender from inside the office room.

One way is to drill hole in the wall and then connect an Ethernet cable into this wifi extender and put it through this hole into the room. Thus, a simple hole and an Ethernet cable.

Another way is to put a socket on the wall outside and another on the inside of the room that bridges the two sides of the wall. Then take a short cable from the wifi extender to this socket and use a longer cable inside the room.

I am not sure which of these method is better. Is there a third better method?

Comment: More or less a duplicate. See https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/104983/18078

Comment: The third, much better method is to run an Ethernet cable from your router to somewhere nearby to add another access point, but that method usually is a lot more work than what you proposed.

Comment: See, I am able to connect to the wifi of the extender. But, there is something wrong with this laptop that causes the wifi to stop working intermittently. Either it is a bug in the drivers, or the wifi adapter inside is faulty or something or the other. In any case, I need to use Ethernet cable specifically to make my life easier.

Comment: @Ecnerwal, how will the low voltage cable port be installed if we are not dealing with dry wall?

Comment: I don't see anything in the question that says "we are not dealing with drywall" - you cut a hole to fit either a low voltage ring or an old-work box on each side, and connect the port to that ring or box. If you can cut a hole in drywall somewhat neatly, you don't need to do any drywall finishing, as the port trim plate will cover the raw edge of the hole.

Comment: Do this: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/289808/97780